# Laravel 5.3 - Laravel DB transaction and notification sends email on failed transaction?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Using the below transaction, I fire an event, which  runs the two listeners listed below the event. The issue is when the first event  `AddQuestionToQuestionsTable` fails for any reason, the `DB` data gets rolled back correctly because of `DB::rollback`, but the laravel notification email I have setup and fired in 
the second listener `QuestionAddedNotificationSend` gets sent out regardless of the error, so whether there was an error or not.

If there was an error in the transaction, we would not want to send the email. Note: I may add additional listeners that also insert into the `DB`, so I would need to know how to only fire off the emails when the transaction is successful.

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    event(new LaravelQuestionPosted($question, $user));
    // Listeners: AddQuestionToQuestionsTable
    // Listeners: QuestionAddedNotificationSend
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    // something went wrong
}

DB::commit();
```

Anyone know how to make it work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `true` as the third parameter when dispatching the event with  `event()` to have the listen handling halted when any of the handlers returns a non-null value or throws an exceptions.

Comment: The events may be queued/broadcasted, so I am not sure still how to set it up. Do you mind sharing some pseudo code to show how you would approach it?

Comment: Can you try `event(new LaravelQuestionPosted($question, [], true))` and see if it behaves as required? The inner exceptions should be caught by the framework then return `false`, which should then halt the event handling, queued or not.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. What are the `[], true` parameters for that you passed to the event? By inner exception, you mean a try/catch block in each listener that would return false in the catch block?

Comment: You're firing an event, which is handled by `Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::dispatch()`. If you look at the method signature, you can pass `$payload` and `$halt` optionally. By default, events are not halted on a failed listener, so I recommended you pass `true` to flag that behavior.

Comment: Sorry, I realized there are more variables I need to pass, like this `event(new LaravelQuestionPosted($question, $user))` so how can I fit the `$user` as well in your suggestion of `event(new LaravelQuestionPosted($question, [], true))`?

Comment: Looking at it now, I put the new parameters inside the LaravelQuestionPosted constructor instead of the event method, so I can see why you were confused. Try `event(new LaravelQuestionPosted($question, $user), [], true)`

Comment: Yup, that snippet makes it a lot clearer :) I tried to have the DB insert fail on purpose in the first listener (by inserting into a non existent column name), so the notification won't fire off in the second listener, since the first failed. However, it seems that whether I use `event(new LaravelQuestionPosted($question, $user), [], true)` or leave my code as is without the extra `[], true` parameters, the notification does not send out. Is there another way of testing the difference of adding `[], true`?